# Inspect environment variables of a process from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio, I want to inspect environment variables of a process launched from it, like in Process Hacker or Process Explorer.
VS gives very advanced debugging capabilities, probably I'm missing something.

*Background.*

I've got a C++ program built by Visual Studio 2019.

It fails if launched from the Visual Studio IDE, but runs successfully if launched from a .cmd script. Cmd script sets additional environment variables, and I want to mimic this behavior with setting those variables from Project properties -> Debugging. I have done it before, and everything was working.

Now something has changed, and I'd like to figure out what.

Security policies of our company don't allow me to use Process Hacker and ProcessExplorer. If I try to launch any of these programs they are terminated by the corporate soft, installed on my PC.

Also, I'd like to avoid adding code that would retrieve these variables and print them.

So, in Visual Studio, is there something that can show environment variables for me?

**Update** The issue is indeed in environment vars. Specifically in the way, Visual Studio sets them. No crashes, if I set required variables globally from system control panel. However, something strange happens if I set them via project properties of Visual Studio.

Comment: `system("env")` or just read the environment from within your program?

Comment: `env` is for Linux. And I'd like to avoid adding such debug code.

Comment: Is the process dependent on the current working directory eg relative file paths ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes it is, but VS launches it from the same directory as that cmd script.

Comment: Why did you leap to the conclusion the problem is due to different env vars? Even if that is the cause you will still need to modify your program to report the env vars it received in order to compare those it receives from the ".cmd" script versus from Visual Studio. The failure should provide sufficient information to debug this problem. Since it obviously doesn't that is the first thing I would fix.

Comment: @KurtisRader, it was just an assumption. I have fixed similar problem before with correct setting of env vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the debug mode, you can save a process dump (Debug - Save Dump As - Minidump with heap) and then inspect this .dmp file with a hex editor (or Notepad if file is small) searching for an environment variable name.